# Assigning version labels in model_config_file fails

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have versions 1 and 2 of a model and I'm trying to assign them labels, following the instructions at https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_config#assigning_string_labels_to_model_versions_to_simplify_canary_and_rollback

I have exported the two versions in `/path/to/model/1` and `/path/to/model/2` respectively and I'm starting the server with the following command:

`tensorflow_model_server --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=models.config`

The following `models.config` file works, and results in only serving version `1` (and if the `specific` message is omitted, version `2` is served as expected since it corresponds to the highest number):

```
model_config_list {
    config {
        name: 'm1'
        base_path: '/path/to/model/'
        model_platform: 'tensorflow'
        model_version_policy {
        specific {
            versions: 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that I can use the server to send requests to the model and perform inference as expected. However if I try to add `version_labels` by using this config file:

```
model_config_list {
    config {
        name: 'm1'
        base_path: '/path/to/model/'
        model_platform: 'tensorflow'
        model_version_policy {
        specific {
            versions: 1
        }
        version_labels {
            key: 'current'
            value: 1
        }
    }
}
```

then launching the server fails with the following error:

`Failed to start server. Error: Failed precondition: Request to assign label to version 1 of model m1, which is not currently available for inference`.

I've also noticed that changing the `value` field to a non-existent version folder yields a similar result:

`Failed to start server. Error: Failed precondition: Request to assign label to version 1234 of model m1, which is not currently available for inference`.

I'm using:

```
TensorFlow ModelServer: 1.12.0-rc0+dev.sha.87470f0
TensorFlow Library: 1.12.0
```

I couldn't find any SO questions on the topic of `version_labels` and the available tensorflow documentation seems incomplete and outdated (for instance it doesn't mention the need to pass `model_platform: 'tensorflow'` in the config file).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config

> Please note that **labels can only be assigned to model versions that
>   are loaded and available for serving**. Once a model version is
>   available, one may reload the model config on the fly, to assign a
>   label to it (can be achieved using HandleReloadConfigRequest RPC
>   endpoint).

Maybe you should delete the label related part first, then start the tensorflow serving, and finally add the label related part to the config file on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

More recently, it is possible to assign labels to models that are not yet loaded provided the `--allow_version_labels_for_unavailable_models=true` flag is specified (in the same place you specify your `--model_config_file=...` variable. (In my case, I do this in a docker-compose.yaml file.)

For more information, see the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config), which at the time of writinng says,

> If you would like to assign a label to a version that is not yet loaded (for ex. by supplying both the model version and the label at startup time) then you must set the --allow_version_labels_for_unavailable_models flag to true, which allows new labels to be assigned to model versions that are not loaded yet.